# How to merge 2 tables according to 2 variables in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have table a and table b. I want to merge them together by variables "year" and "province(region in table b)", so that "province" in table b can appear in table a.I don't know how to do it in R. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPDVc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omp7x.jpg)

Comment: You are more likely to get useful help if you make your problem reproducible with a minimal example, & show what you have tried so far. Screenshots of your data don't count. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In addition, "province" in table a & "region" in table b aren't formatted in the same way, so you'll need to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` as below:

```
merge(a, b, by=c("year","province"))
```

This will merge two `data frames` by column year and province.

Comment: You can use more than one variable. You just need to mention in by as I did. See here: https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

First, rename the variable in table a from province to region, so that it's easier to process:

```
names(taba)[names(taba)=="province"] <- "region"
```

The structure of your data frames will be somewhat like this:

```
taba <- data.frame("a", "b", "c")

tabb <- data.frame("a", "b", "d")
```

After you have renamed the columns, you just need to do a left_join with the dplyr library.

```
library(dplyr)

tabc <- left_join(taba, tabb)
```

Comment: i don't understand. where is the  parameter "by="

Comment: @zhang the parameter "by" can be put after the to tables left_join(taba, tabb, by = column), but if you have matching names then it automatically joins on those ones, so  in this case you don't need to specify it.